# vector of eigenvalues is an eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, recreational-mathematics

When is it the case that the vector $\begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 \\ \lambda_2 \\ ... \end{bmatrix}$ of eigenvalues of a matrix is in fact an eigenvector of that matrix?

Comment: $AX=KX$ . When $A=I$ and $K=1$ then i think condition is satisfied. Someone confirm this

Comment: But are there any other solutions than $A=I$? Obviously anything is an eigenvector of the identity matrix.

Comment: There is no default ordering of the eigenvalues, so how do you choose the ordering? Do you assume they are real and sort them?

Comment: A nontrivial solution for any ordering would be interesting. But I sort of see now why this is a strange question to ask: the $n$ eigenvalues do not 'naturally' form a vector, because they aren't ordered.

Answer (score 1):

To make our lives easier, let's try $2\times 2$:

$$\left \{ \begin{align*}
  \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix} u \\ v \end{pmatrix} = u
  \begin{pmatrix} u \\ v \end{pmatrix} \\[5pt]
  \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix} v \\ u \end{pmatrix} = v
  \begin{pmatrix} v \\ u \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*} \right.$$

On solving, we have
\begin{align*}
  \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} &=
  \begin{pmatrix} u & v \\ v & u \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix} u & 0 \\ 0 & v \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix} u & v \\ v & u \end{pmatrix}^{-1} \\[5pt] &=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{u^2+uv+v^2}{u+v} & -\frac{uv}{u+v} \\
    \frac{uv}{u+v}         &  \frac{uv}{u+v}
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

For $u\begin{pmatrix} v \\ u \end{pmatrix}$ and 
$v\begin{pmatrix} u \\ v \end{pmatrix}$ convention:

\begin{align*}
  \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} &=
  \begin{pmatrix} v & u \\ u & v \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix} u & 0 \\ 0 & v \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix} v & u \\ u & v \end{pmatrix}^{-1} \\[5pt] &=
  \begin{pmatrix}
     \frac{uv}{u+v} & \frac{uv}{u+v} \\
    -\frac{uv}{u+v} & \frac{u^2+uv+v^2}{u+v}
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
For $n$ distinct assigned eigenvalues, there are $n!$ permutations of eigenvectors, so there are $\displaystyle \, n! \binom{n!}{n}$ of possible matrices.

Comment: Well, at least this is one nontrivial solution. Of course, if the assigned eigenvalues are $u, v$, there's no reason to assume that both $\begin{bmatrix} u \\ v \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} v \\ u \end{bmatrix}$ are eigenvectors, so you don't really have the second constraint. And the general $n \times n$ case looks hard with this approach... but have to start somewhere!